# Twig - date function's format have unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, symfony, date, datetime, twig

I use the `Date` function in twig to render a datetime field from an Entity.

When I use

```
entityName.dateCreated|date('Ymd') ==> 20160316
```

This is correct but poorly readable.

Now the funny part is when I tried to add / or - as a separator, twig interpret it as an arithmetic operator.

```
bit.dateCreated|date('Y/m/d') ==> 42

bit.dateCreated|date('Y-m-d') ==> 1997
```

Here is my Entity field

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateCreated;
```

Edited

```
{% for bit in buzzindextab  %}{{  bit.dateCreated|date('d-m-Y') }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

{{  dump(bit.dateCreated) }} restult

```
DateTime {#687 ▼
  +"date": "2016-03-16 12:10:33.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
}
```

{{ "now"|date('Y-m-d') }} ==> 1996

Comment: There is difference between accessing object in twig using {%%} instead of {{}}

Comment: Can you post all your twig code, and a dump of bit.dateCreated => {{ dump(bit.dateCreated) }} ?  
Try to do {{ now|date('Y/m/d') }} and {{ now|date('Y-m-d') }} and post results

Comment: @Nicolas thanks for your help. I edited the question with the result of your comment.

Comment: Have you a standard symfony setup ?  
have you specific twig confiuration in config*.yml ?  
Can you test with a php file outside your project, simple new dateTime() and date output to see how it goes : http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-examples first example will do

Comment: It's all fine in php, inside the same controler that is calling my twig template if I do $date = new \DateTime('2000-01-01'); echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); I have a correct output : 2000-01-01

Comment: I don't think I have a special Symfony set up. I can post my config.yml if needed. Symfony version is 2.8.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106616/discussion-between-nicolas-and-kaizoku-gambare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help received in the comments we figured it out that the output of the Date function was interpreted by Javascript code.

So I just had to protected the output with quote

```
'{{  bit.dateCreated|date('d-m-Y') }}'
```